# How to Export all data in schedule after filled put another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formatting, string-formatting, transpose

How to export all the data in the schedule after filling it out and putting the data in another sheet, such as the name of the employee with its dates from the beginning of the month to the end of the month and exporting it on a page, like this page you made
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hhEs01waUxXkkVT1ZjvTpzGZ4IBpOjIYstQN4pu2QWY/edit?usp=sharing
[schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px7YG.png)
[all data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07raT.png)

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail.   In your example you have a sheet formatted like a calendar, in the other tab it is just a person's name, a date, and present.   Here is a guide on how to clarify things: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({TEXT(Sheet1!C8:8, "dd-mm-yyyy"); 
 FILTER(Sheet1!C8:800, Sheet1!B8:B800=A2)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, How to repeat name"sara" depend number date like: from A2 to A29 name Sara

Comment: @Han try in A3: `=INDEX(IF(B3:B="";;A2))`

Comment: good ! Thank you, How can I export all the contents of the Schedule in a Sheet with formula, and how can I go to the other name and repeat the same step as the name Sara?

Comment: good ! Thank you, How can I export all the contents of the Schedule in a Sheet with formula, and how can I go to the other name and repeat the same step as the name Sara?